# Please check my problem about SI prefixes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, si-units

2.2 A single logic gate in a prototype integrated circuit is found to be
capable of switching from the “on” state to the “off” state in 12 ps. This
corresponds to: (a) 1.2 ns; (b) 120 ns; (c) 1200 ns; (d) 12,000 ns.

The answer is (d). It isn't 0.012ns, is it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: 12 picoseconds = 12,000 femtoseconds or .012 nanoseconds per my understanding, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#Prefixes

Comment: also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picosecond